# Go back to former page for beginners

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

I'm super new to Kotlin and haven't even used Java very much. Although I've worked more with C# and C++ I'm still an amateur. Anyway, I'm trying to get a basic back function going in the app I'm building, where by pressing the system back button you return to the fragment you were at before. All the tutorials I've looked at don't actually manage the changing of the fragment. Currently I am able to detect the back press and consume it, but the stack I'm using to manage the order in which you should go back seems to run into problems and I am seemingly unable to change the fragment from within a fragment.

This is the code I have in the fragment classes located in the overridden OnCreateView function

```
activity?.onBackPressedDispatcher?.addCallback(this, object : OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
            override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
                if (!SectionsPagerAdapter.pos.isEmpty()) {
                    println("Should go to " + SectionsPagerAdapter.pos.pop())
                }
            }
        })
```

And here is the code building the stack (with non relevant parts taken out)

```
class SectionsPagerAdapter(private val context: Context, fm: FragmentManager)
    : FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fm) {

    companion object {
        var pos = Stack<Int>()
        var posCurrent = 0
    }
override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
            pos.push(posCurrent)
            posCurrent = position
    }
}
```

The problem with the stack is that the popped number does not match what it should. For example, it will often return the index for the fragment it is currently on, or possibly the index for a fragment that was several clicks back. I honestly have no idea why.

As for changing the fragment based on that number, I simply can't seem to call anything that does anything. For example if I put this into the handleOnBackPressed() function

```
               context?.let { fragmentManager?.let { it1 ->
                    SectionsPagerAdapter(it,
                        it1
                    )
                } }?.getItem(SectionsPagerAdapter.pos.pop())
```

Then nothing happens. If I try calling setPrimaryItem I need a container and an 'object' that I don't have in order to do so.

Basically I just don't know how to do this. Please Help.

Comment: Managing a stack of Fragments is somewhat complicated and problematic with the android library classes. You might try working with the library by @EpicPandaForce. https://github.com/Zhuinden/simple-stack

Comment: It's not a stack of fragments, just a stack of integers I'm using to reference which of the fragments I need to instantiate upon back being pressed

Comment: Although looking at that library it still may be very useful. I'll take a look